# How to plot multiple lines on the same y-axis using Plotly Express in Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I just installed plotly express. And I am trying to do something simple - plot each column of my data frame on the same y-axis with the index as x-axis. Here are questions/observations:

Is it necessary for the data frame to have index as a column to be used as x-axis ? Can I not directly use the index for x-axis?
How can I add multiple traces as were called in plotly on y-axis for the same x-axis ?

Please note that, I am not trying to add traces using plotly, rather trying to use plotly-express.

Also, there a few similar posts online, the closest was [this](https://community.plot.ly/t/multiple-traces-plotly-express/23360): 
https://community.plot.ly/t/multiple-traces-plotly-express/23360 
However, this post shows how you can add a scatter, not a line. I want to plot a line and there is no add_line similar to add_scatter shown in the example here.

Appreciate any help in advance

**Sample code:**

```
import plotly.express as px 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# Get some data
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

# Plot 
fig = px.line(df, x='Date', y='AAPL.High')

# Only thing I figured is - I could do this 
fig.add_scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['AAPL.Low']) # Not what is desired - need a line 

# Show plot 
fig.show()
```

**PLot:**

[image]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

#### Short answer:

```
fig = px.line(df, x='Date', y=df.columns[1:-6])
```

Where `df.columns` are the column names of the columns returned as a list, or a subset of the columns using, for example, `df.columns[1:-6]`

---

#### The details

Your code works fine  But if you specifically do not want to apply the (somewhat laborious) `add_trace()` function to each line, you can use `px.line()`. This used to require you to transform your data from a [wide to long](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/wide-and-long-data/) format. But not anymore, so just define an index and name the columns you'd like to plot. Or reference all or a subset of your dataframe columns through, for ecxample, `y=df.columns[1:-6]`

#### Code 1:

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# data
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
fig = px.line(df, x='Date', y=df.columns[1:-6])

# Show plot 
fig.show()
```

#### Plot:

[image]

If you'd like to know how to do the same thing with data of a long format, here's how you do that too using pandas and plotly:

#### Code 2:

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# data
df_wide = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
df_long=pd.melt(df_wide, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['AAPL.Open', 'AAPL.High', 'AAPL.Low', 'AAPL.Close', 'mavg'])

# plotly 
fig = px.line(df_long, x='Date', y='value', color='variable')

# Show plot 
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. And when you want to process all columns you can get column names from df_wide object so your code would be universal for any csv with date in 1st column and values in other columns: `df_long=pd.melt(df_wide, id_vars=df_wide.columns[0], value_vars=df_wide.columns[1:])`

Comment: Please explain the magic number `-6`.

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar That's for indexing in `df.columns[1:-6]` and simply drops the last six columns in the list `df.columns`

Comment: This is a very helpful example. Thank you

Comment: @jasonm Thanks for the feedback! Glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 13):

Not sure what type of line your looking for, but have you tried something like below

```
fig.add_scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['AAPL.Low'],mode='lines')
```

On a standard scatter you can set the mode to be any combination of lines, markers and text.

Comment: This might be helpful, but the question was about plotly.express, not standard plotly.

Answer (score -6):

There is one method to add plots in a single graph.

```
 import matplotlib.plotly as plt
 plt.figure(figsize=(-,-))
 ax1 = plt.plot(x1,y1)
 ax2 = plt.plot(x2,y2)
 ax3 = plt.plot(x3,y3)
 plt.legend(handles=[ax1,ax2,ax3],figsize=10)
```

Comment: OP asked about plotly. Answer is about matplotlib.