# How to plot multiple lines on the same y-axis and put y lables, vertical line using Plotly Express in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly-python

I am using this link to solve my doubts:

[How to plot multiple lines on the same y-axis using Plotly Express in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142058/how-to-plot-multiple-lines-on-the-same-y-axis-using-plotly-express-in-python)

I am trying to plot multiple lines in same plot. Also, I want to add `data-labels ( Y-values)` on every line that I plot.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
def plot_func(data):
    
    fig = px.line(data, x="yyyymm", y="sells", color='model')
    fig.show()
```

The resultant plot is:

[image]

I want to add `y-values` on every line. Also, if you notice my `x axis` is in format `yyyymm` which I have converted to string by appending `_` at end otherwise plotly converts it to number. Is there a better approach to convert it to dates?

How can I add a `vertical dash line` where `x=201912_` and put `title` to my plots?