# LIne graph using plotly

Tags: python, plotly

With this script , it is open 2 dashboards and so 2 graphs
How i can modify it to see all on the same graph ?
dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame( df_abs.to_numpy()[:, 1:].T).reset_index().melt(id_vars="index")
    fig = px.line(df, x="index", y="value", color="variable")
    fig.show()
```

script dot plotly:

```
df_abs = pd.DataFrame(df_abs.loc[outlier].iloc[1:]).reset_index().melt(id_vars="index")
fig = px.line(df_abs, x="index", y="value", color="variable")
fig.show()

df = pd.DataFrame( df_abs.to_numpy()[:, 1:].T).reset_index().melt(id_vars="index")
fig = px.line(df, x="index", y="value", color="variable")
fig.show()
```

Comment: Have you read the Plotly documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot multiple lines on the same y-axis using Plotly Express in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142058/how-to-plot-multiple-lines-on-the-same-y-axis-using-plotly-express-in-python)

Comment: Also, you should share your dataframe, or a dummy version of it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I added my dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `plotly.graph_objects` instead of `plotly.express`.

`plotly.express` is great for quick plots but it is somewhat limited compared to `plotly.graph_objects`.

Here is a dummy example using 2 dataframes to make it similar to your case.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df1 = px.data.gapminder().query("country in ['Canada']")
df2 = px.data.gapminder().query("country in ['Italy']")

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df1["lifeExp"], y=df1["gdpPercap"], mode='lines', name='Canada'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2["lifeExp"], y=df2["gdpPercap"], mode='lines', name='Italy'))
fig.show()
```

[image]